# Logarithmic Transform of proportions (Weber's law)

Tags: logarithm

Given we have a function as follows (context is the Weber-Fechner law):

$$\frac{\Delta x}{x} = C \tag 1$$

Plotting here $\Delta x$ as a function of $x,$ this is clearly a linear function with a slope of $C.$

Now a log-transform of (1) results in:

$$\log\left(\frac{\Delta x} x\right) = \log(C) \tag 2 $$

and hence:

$$ \log\left(\Delta x\right) = \log(x) + \log(C) \tag 3$$

Now it is stated that plotting $\log(\Delta x)$ as a function of $\log(x)$ results in a linear function with slope $1$ and intercept $C.$ How can I see (analytically) that this is true?

Comment: First of all, it's not true: most likely you mean the intercept is $\log C.$  With this understanding, there's nothing additional to see because (3) explicitly exhibits a linear function with unit slope and intercept $\log C.$

Comment: It seems there's nothing left to say, then.

Comment: You've completely solved the problem, but you don't seem to realize it.

Comment: No, I don't realize it, that is the point of asking. Is it really not possible to explain instead of making semi sarcastic comments?

Comment: I don't think anyone is being sarcastic on purpose. They are just puzzled about what you're puzzled about. If you write $\log {\Delta}x =: v, \log x =: u, \log C =: b$ then you have $v = b + u$, which is linear in $u$ with unit slope: does that help?

Comment: But in this link, again page 2 second last section, they say that the intercept is C - without redefinition - this is what is confusing me as it seems to me that the intercept must be log(C)? Or am I misunderstanding this because it is a log-log function? http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~msl/courses/0044/handouts/Weber.pdf

Comment: The source uses different notation, but you're right and the source is inconsistent. But watch out: many writers would feel free to think or imply that notation for uninteresting constants is defined informally and locally. Other way round, it's often considered pedantic and/or unnecessary to introduce a new symbol for something used just once or to insist that a meaning has changed.

Comment: I learned this the hard way in 1972 when I spent about a week trying to understand one short paper; the last time I read it it took about 10 minutes because I then knew the idea inside out; and I knew that the author was extremely undisciplined about notation and that -- undeservedly -- journal reviewers and journal editor just assumed that he knew exactly what he meant.

Comment: yes exactly, but as a beginner you don't know, and feedback like yours can be much more helpful than a "it is obvious". So, many thanks:)!